# How to ensure atomicity of multiple lines of code together in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, atomic

I am writing Pyspark code in Azure Databricks notebook where at the end of the notebook I need to write results back to 3 different places (2 tables in Database of databricks and 1 folder in ADLS ) and I have 3 different functions (WriteResultsToTable1, WriteResultsToTable2, WriteResultsToADLS) created for this operation and I call them in my main function and thus there are 3 lines of code for doing this operation but I want either results should be written successfully to all 3 locations or to none i.e. either all 3 lines of code run successfully in my main function or none of them

Can someone please  suggest some way of achieving this in databricks using pyspark?

Comment: Basically, you want ACIDity on a distributed system ?  https://blog.knoldus.com/spark-acid-compliant-or-not/  tl;dr : **spark is not ACID compliant**

Answer (score 1):

As Steven mentioned, Spark is not ACID compliant. You could however create another table to track whether your results are written to Table1, Table2 and ADLS. This will allow you to create a retry logic and allow your process to be "atomic".

For this to work, your table that you'll use to track the process could have 5 columns:

1. ProcessName
2. Current_Timestamp
3. Flag for check if Table1 is written
4. Flag to check if Table2 is written
5. Flag to check if ADLS is written

At the start of your notebook, you can write logic to check for the latest timestamp for that process and ensure that all three flags indicate the results are written for the latest timestamp. In the event one of the flags indicate that the results are not written, your logic should dictate that it writes to the respective target table/ADLS with the current state of data.

Do note: Only update the flags for each WRITE step after each Table/ADLS is written to.